# mocking Executorservice field in unit test

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I have this service class that I am trying to Unit test using mockito but is failing:

```
@Service("processor")
public class AsyncProcessor extends Processor {

    @Value("${queue.size}")
    private int queueSize;

    @Value("${executor.corePoolSize}")
    private int corePoolSze;

    @Value("${executor.maxPoolSize}")
    private int maxPoolSize;

    @Value("${executor.keepAliveTime}")
    private int keepAliveTime;

    private final JobRunner jobRunner;

    private final ExecutorService executorService;

    public AsyncProcessor(final MyRepo repo,
                              final JobRunner jobRunner) {
        super(repo);
        this.jobRunner = jobRunner;
        executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSze, maxPoolSize, keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                                                 new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(queueSize));
    }
    ///

}
```

So I have written this test class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class AsyncProcessorTest{

    @Mock
    private MyRepo repo;

    @Mock
    private JobRunner jobRunner;


    @InjectMocks
    private AsyncProcessor asyncProcessor;


    @Test
    public void someTest() {
    }

}
```

When I run my tests, i get error with inject mocks.

The error appears when it tried to instantiate the executorService on the constructor.

My question is how can I mock it and use it and overcome this error?

Comment: BTW: `corePoolSze, maxPoolSize, keepAliveTime` are all equal to `0` when the constructor is invoked, they are injected only **after** the constructor code has run.

Comment: yes so now I am initializing executor service outside of constructor as field

Comment: And to mock the `executorService` you'd have to use `PowerMockito` to mock the constructor of `ThreadPoolExecutor`, or simply let it also be injected via the constructor

Comment: I can use reflection with field setter, but this only works if I directly initialize executor service with pool size etc without @value

Comment: Remove final modifier from ExecutorService.

Comment: This is why it is generally not a good idea to initialize dependencies in the constructor using `new`. Rather provide them as arguments to the constructor. Since this is Spring, I'd have a `@Bean` method creating the `AsyncProcessor` and let it create the executor service. That way, it will be easy to test with a mock.

Comment: Can you provide an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would initialize the service a bit differently - instead of having the protperties in this class and creating the executorService in the c'tor - make it a separate bean and inject it.

in your application context:

```
@Value("${queue.size}")
private int queueSize;

@Value("${executor.corePoolSize}")
private int corePoolSze;

@Value("${executor.maxPoolSize}")
private int maxPoolSize;

@Value("${executor.keepAliveTime}")
private int keepAliveTime;

@Bean
ExecutorService executorService() {
  return new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSze, maxPoolSize, keepAliveTime, 
        TimeUnit.SECONDS,new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(queueSize));
}
```

And then inject it in the c'tor of your service.
This will allow you to provide a mock in your unit test

Comment: And maybe create a `@ConfigurationProperties` class for the data fields.

Comment: thanks, what I was looking for :).. resulting in a simpler processor and tests without reflection code